# how to differentiate html elements with same class name

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

hey am trying to get the contents of class medal which is a class of gold, but when i type it as class medal I also get contents of silver and bronze how can i get the contents of first class only. below is the html code

```
<ul class="table2 ajax-content">
<ul class="medal-box">
<li>
<div class="medal"> <span>G</span> <span class="num">0</span> </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="medal silver"> <span>S</span> <span class="num">0</span> </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="medal bronze"> <span>B</span> <span class="num">1</span> </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<ul class="medal-box">
<li>
<div class="medal"> <span>G</span> <span class="num">0</span> </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="medal silver"> <span>S</span> <span class="num">0</span> </div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="medal bronze"> <span>B</span> <span class="num">1</span> </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

below is the python code trying to scrape the medal

```
seasons =  results.find_all(class_='medal-box')
    silvers =  results.find_all(class_='medal silver')
    for silver in silvers:
        num_silver =siver.find(class_="num").get_text()
        print(num_silver)
    bronzes =  results.find_all(class_='medal bronze')
    for bronze in bronzes:
        num_bronze =bronze.find(class_="num").get_text()
        print(num_bronze)
        k = len(bronzes)
    golds =  results.find_all(class_='medal')
    for gold in golds:
        num_gold =gold.find(class_="num").get_text()
        print(num_gold)
    ~~~
here is what am getting 
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
1
instead of getting
0
0
1
1
0
0
```

Comment: I do not see any *medal gold* class. Where is it?

Comment: the class with medal only in the site is for gold. so how can i get contents for class with medal since if i just call it class medal i also get contents for bronze and silver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the one of the medal_boxes element instead of whole soup. I have rewritten your code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('content_of_page')

medal_boxes = soup.find_all('ul', class_ = 'medal-box')

for i in medal_boxes:
    mmedal = i.find('div', class_ = 'medal')
    medal_silver = i.find('div', class_ = 'medal silver')
    medal_bronze = i.find('div', class_ = 'medal bronze')
```

To get text out of that class you can use `.text` or `.get_text()`

Comment: this only gives one 0 instead of two for mmedal

Comment: am not getting you

Comment: @ChrisPine if that worked, please award my answer as a correct one - by clicking the ,,tick'' button. Here you can read more about that https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers